# How to detect the real orientation of a video recorded by mobile with "auto rotate" disabled

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

When you record a video, the rotation metadata has 4 possible values (0, 90, 180 and 270) and it stores how the device was held when starting the recording.

But mobile phones has also a feature to enable or disable "auto rotation" of screen.

It's very typical, nowadays, to have that feature disable, and many people record videos with the phone horizontally, but since the "auto rotation" is disable, the metadata stores like the video was recorded as vertically.

How to handle this?

Comment: **(1)** Are we talking about MP4 video here? And also in what context do you ask when you say _"How to handle this?"_ I mean is your code trying to edit the file bytes or just to play the video (on a rotated surface)? **(2)** Is the problem solved if you edit that metadata to become a different value? if yes, does the widths/heights also change? If those resolution numbers stay same regardless of orientation changing then maybe read those values to estimate, eg: portrait orientation `90` cannot have a width larger than the height, so now you know the real orientation.

Comment: I mean how can we put in the right orientation a video recorded in a mobile phone, that has rotated the phone but has the auto rotate feature disabled. In this case, the video metadata will have (for example) "this is vertical video", but the video was recorded 90 degrees rotated. So it's not possible to put it in right orientation

Comment: I can't speak about other formats but in MP4 header there is a setting for rotation, so the idea is to find a "vertical" and change it to a "horizontal" then hopefully media players show it correctly. I don't have such a file (as you've described) at hand, please provide a link to a short testable file?